Forward ref with Material ui and custom component
i am having issue with forwarding ref using Material UI's Textfield with customComponent as InputProps
In short: I have a customized Mui Outlined Textfield. And it can either be input (just an ordinary text input) or have a custom component. In the example custom ToggleSwitch. And this is where all the issues start
Here is a link: Code SandBox
At the moment i am getting couple of errors:

Failed prop type: Invalid prop inputComponent supplied to ForwardRef(InputBase). Expected an element type that can hold a ref.

Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?
Check the render method of MuiOutlinedInputInput.


and i am stuck. I have tried to wrap components with forwardRef but to no avail.
I am guessing iam using a wrong approach to this so any idea is welcome.
thank you

<CustomInput> is a Customized <TextField>.
In your case,
<TextField
  InputProps = {{
    inputComponent: customComponent,
  }}
/>

inputComponent: customComponent, should be:

A native HTML element like input.
A React component that is wrapped with React.forwardRef and can
correctly handle refs.

BUT, inside of the "App.js", what you passed is a render function. Apparently, neither of the above two conditions is met.

    customComponent={(props) => {
      return (
        <CustomToggleSwitch {...props} offLabel="No" onLabel="Yes" />
      );
    }}


So, the thing is here: you need to pass a React component that is wrapped with React.forwardRef to customComponent.
